# how to obtain a C array from an std::vector<std::reference_wrapper>

Tags: c, c++11, stdvector, reference-wrapper

I'm new to C++11 and I'm confused about the usage of `std::refence_wrapper` class.

let's consider the example shown in 
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper ,which shuffles the elements contained in a standard `std::vector`, i.e:

```
std::vector<int> l(10); 
std::iota(l.begin(), l.end(), -4);
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>> v(l.begin(), l.end());
std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()});
```

Now, if consider the original vector `l`, I have that `l.data()` returns a pointer to the internal array, which can I use in a C application.

Instead, it's not clear to me instead what is returned by `v.data()`. I tried various combinations of surely wrong casts, such as `int* p = (int*)(v.data()->get())` without obtaining correct results (the swapped values).

My goal is to interface a C++ application (which gives me a vector of reference wrappers) with an old C library. Can you point me which is the most correct way to obtain a C-like array from the vector `v`, after the shuffle shown in the example? Do I need to copy all the elements one-by-one in another vector?
Is there any C++11 class which can help me in the job?
Thank you

Comment: In your code, `l` is a `list`, not a `vector`. It doesn't have a `data()` member function and if it did it wouldn't point to a C-style array.

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake copy & pasting the snippet.
I edited the question, so now l is a vector.

Comment: Why do you need `std::reference_wrapper<int>` in the first place? Do you plan to access the original array through these references?

Comment: @n.m. yes. The general idea is similar to the one reported in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114658/return-row-or-column-from-a-2d-array in which multiple std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>> provide different 'views' of the internal data structure.  
Of course, when I access to the elements of the vector<reference_wrapper<int>> I want to modify data in the original data structure. But in this question, when I speak about a C-array obtained by .data() method, I just want to read data, not to modify it.

Answer (score 5):

`reference_wrapper` is a C++ type; you're not *supposed* to be able to just hand it over to a C API. If you want to pass something to a C API, then it needs to be something that C and C++ share.

If that C API takes an array of pointers to integers, then pointers to integers is what your `vector` should store. Otherwise yes, you have to copy those integers into something that C can speak.

Comment: I see your point. What do you think about the solution that I propose? (I just edited my question).

Comment: @MarcoRandazzo: Answers go in the answer box, not in your question.

Answer (score 0):

After more thinking, I came up with this solution:

```
std::vector<int> l(10); 
std::iota(l.begin(), l.end(), -4);
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>> v(l.begin(), l.end());
std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()});

std::vector<int> vec2 (v.begin(), v.end());
int* p = vec2.data();
```

I'm thus copying the elements from `v` to a new vector `vec2`. The C array `p` obtained from `vec2` is now valid.

I wonder if there is a better way to do the job...

Comment: If C expects an `int*`, then you have to have either a `int[]` or a `vector<int>` that holds the final data. There's no "better" way.

Comment: If you can change the C to expect an array of `int` pointers, then you can have a `vector<int*>` the entire time. You need to manually handle the derefencing then instead of letting `std::reference_wrapper` do it but it doesn't take an extra copy for the C side.